# Why does an unnecessary comma before an object property not cause a syntax error in this case?

Tags: javascript, syntax, syntax-error

Why does the following code example not throw a syntax error like `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','`?

If I define the following I get the syntax error mentioned above.

```
const a = {
,
a: 1
}
```

But on the other hand if I define the following there is no error thrown although the property b is not defined due to the condition being false.

```
const a = {
...(false && {b: 1}),
a: 1
}
```

What happens to the comma above `a: 1` or why is there no error thrown?

Comment: The presence of the spread and the expression is the key difference.  Those *exist* in the object initializer, while in the first sample there is nothing whatsoever before the comma.

Comment: You can simplify that to `const a = {...false, a: 1}`. Which is not the same as `const a = {, a: 1}`.

Comment: You're thinking that the spread syntax works by textual substitution, that's not how it works.

Comment: Computer languages use very strict syntactic rules; there is no place for the multiple ambiguities specific to "human" languages